# Socket.poll don't return true

Tags: c#, sockets, polling

In C#, `socket.poll` sometimes returns false. However Winshark indicates that there are packets.

I found some answers, but nothing definitive. Is there any possibility that its because `Interrupt Moderation` setting is open?

Can someone with the same problem give some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why should you use the Socket.Poll? Just use `socket.Read()` or `socket.BeginRead()`. It will return when there is data.

Comment: Is any data missing using polling?  I don't think any data is missing.  I think the PC driver or windows is simply combining receive packets and you need to separate the data.  TCP specification allows messages to be combined and split into datagrams with max size of ~1500 bytes.  Servers and Routers are allowed to change datagrams and windows uses timers to send messages from the Ethernet adapter to your application and these timers may split or combine received packets.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen because I want to do something else when there is no data received, rather than block

Comment: @RookieCheng Thats the whole idea of async socket operations.You should read [Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-client-socket). The polling is done very low-level. You don't need a polling thread or timers.